# converting stored procedures from sql server to oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000, oracle10g

We have a massive amount of stored procedures to convert from sql-server 2000 to oracle 10g. Does anyone know of any tool that would achieve this?

We used Oracle SQL developer for this but it seems like it is creating extra cursors for each IF/ELSE condition that was on sql server side.

Has anyone successfully used a tool that would do this?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, no answer, and you have my sympathies.  I've been through this before and it was all manual.  We ended up making distinct migration & test plan tasks for it.

Oracle *will* use cursors in places that look odd for people used to SQL server.  I am not aware of any (simple) way around this.

There seem to be a number of companies out there now offering services or tools to help: [This Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=convert+sql+server+to+oracle&rls=com.microsoft:en-us:IE-SearchBox&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=ie7) shows a bunch.

Don't forget to plan for functional equivalence testing.  Datatype differences may cause issues, and your application development tool(s) may interact differently with Oracle than they do with SQL server. I did this conversion a number of years ago for a PowerBuilder application, and a lot more of that needed updating than we expected.

Comment: agreed. this is a nightmare >_<

Comment: we're still doing it for a PowerBuilder application (o_o)